# How to convert csv file to a xls or xlsx in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I have been trying to convert the .csv file to .xls or .xlsx, and i have been success in do so. But the problem is that the file is not opening. It's showing that unable to open the file format.

These are the following code which i have been using.

```
1. var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
                exportType : new sap.ui.core.util.ExportType({
                    separatorChar : ",",
                    fileExtension : "xlsx",
                    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                }),
                models : oModel,

                rows : {
                    path : "/"
                },
                columns : [ itemsArray ]
            });
            oExport.saveFile(oFileName).always(function() {
                this.destroy();
            });
```

when i download like this the file size will be zero. Hence it does not have any value. And i tried with alternative way.

```
2.var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
                exportType : new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
                    separatorChar : ",",
                    fileExtension : "xlsx",
                    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                }),
                models : oModel,

                rows : {
                    path : "/"
                },
                columns : [ itemsArray ]
            });
            oExport.saveFile(oFileName).always(function() {
                this.destroy();
            });
```

When i use the above code file will be having some data but unable to open it. Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get your data from a Netweaver gateway OData service ?

Comment: Thank you for replying, ya i'm getting data form gateway. But i'm trying download the data which is visible in the front end (view). I can download the data form gateway but the result will not be as i expected. I just want to convert csv to xls or xlsx.

Comment: If you would have been downloading directly from the gateway adding a paramter to the odata request (?$format=xlsx) would have done the job. Through UI5, CSV export works out of the box, Excel export would be tricky

Comment: Thank you, have been trying to do the tricky things : )

Comment: The problem would be that the content of a XSLSX file will not be the same as a CSV file. So just changing the mimeType will not make it a valid Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK sapui5 doesn't provide that functionality out of the box. So you may need to manage it by yourself.

This might help you https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.

We used it to read xlsx files but looks like it helps you to write them as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll definitely go through it.